# Cull top and bottom % of SQL result; exclude percent on query?

Tags: sql, pdo

I'm trying to select rows from a database but excluding the top and bottom 10% from the result. Consider a table as below:

```
  id | score
--------------
   1 |   9
   2 |   7
   3 |   9
   4 |   6
   5 |   1
   6 |   9
   7 |   8
   8 |   5
   9 |   1
  10 |   9
```

Using the below SQL...

```
SELECT SUM(score)/COUNT(*)
    FROM reviews
    ORDER BY score
```

It would yield a mean of `6.4`. I would like it to ignore the top and bottom 10%, however, yielding a mean of `6.75`.

I've looked into a few ways to accomplish this. `TOP # PERCENT` doesn't quite work as I'd hope. Excluding the first and last `COUNT(*)*0.1` rows lacks finesse. There must be an easier way to do this.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something with the `RowNumber()` as below, I have not tested the query may want to change as per your need, Here @From and @To are the your values for the 80% percent that's in current case that is 2 and 9

```
    WITH NumberedMyTable AS
    (
       SELECT
         Id,
         Score,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score) AS RowNumber
     FROM
        MyTable
    )
  SELECT
     SUM(score)/COUNT(*)
  FROM
     NumberedMyTable
  WHERE
      RowNumber BETWEEN @From AND @To
```